# C# input/output with another console application

Tags: c#, process, console-application, stdout

I'm trying to build a c# program that will pass string to an existing console application and will get back string after it is done processing.

Here is how I would want it to work:

```
    public void InitializeUtil(List<object> items)
    {
        Process DataValidationUtilitty = new Process();
        DataValidationUtilitty.StartInfo.FileName = Configuration.DVUTIL;
        DataValidationUtilitty.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        DataValidationUtilitty.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        DataValidationUtilitty.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        DataValidationUtilitty.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        DataValidationUtilitty.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        DataValidationUtilitty.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        DataValidationUtilitty.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InterProcOutputHandler);
        DataValidationUtilitty.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(InterProcOutputHandler);
        DataValidationUtilitty.Start();

        DataValidationUtilitty.BeginOutputReadLine();

        DataValidationUtilitty.StandardInput.WriteLine(items[0].ToString());
    }

    public void InterProcOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data.ToString());
    }

    // And I call
    Program ThisProgram = new Program();
    ThisProgram.InitializeUtil(items);
```

For some obvious reasons this does not work and I don't know why.

Here is a working example:

- I have here executable with DLL that it needs
- I have an input string in `document.json` file
- I have a `.bat` file that will run this executable

[image: File structure]

- Run the program and pass `document.json` as input string
- Pause execution to see the results

[image: Bat file contents]

- Get back correct string

[image: Command line results]

What am I missing here, what don't I understand about this process? I was assured from `dvutils.exe` developers that program does std input,output,error.

Comment: Do you follow all the steps shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), including the call to close the standard input of `Configuration.DVUTIL` and the call to [`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  As an aside, `Process` is disposable and should be wrapped in a `using` statement.

Comment: @dbc Thanks followed each step there and got it to work.